# How do I request the table size from psycopg2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

Experimentally, the following works:

```
from psycopg2 import sql
def table_size(conn, table):
    with conn.cursor() as cu:
        cu.execute(sql.SQL("SELECT pg_table_size({t}), pg_indexes_size({t});").format(t=sql.Literal(table)))
        return cu.fetchall()[0]
```

However, I wonder if I am using [`sql.SQL`/`sql.Literal`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html) correctly.

E.g., how do I combine table and column names with values?

```
def get(conn,table,key,value,column):
    with conn.cursor() as cu:
        cu.execute(sql.SQL("SELECT {c} FROM {t} WHERE {k} = %s;").format(
            c=sql.Identifier(column),t=sql.Identifier(table),k=sql.Identifier(key)),
                   (value, ))
        return cu.fetchall()
```